# How to start Windows XP in Safe Mode when its a VirtualBox guest in a Mac OS X host?

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, virtualization

I've tried tapping F8 as it boots up, but I just get the normal logon screen.  I'm using a Mac Mini with an Apple keyboard, do I need to do something special to get it to recognise F8?

I'm trying to install Guest Additions so that I can use DirectX, which is why I need safe mode.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can force boot in safe mode by using msconfig:

Click on **Start**, then **Run**.
In the Run dialog box, type `msconfig` and press Enter.
The msconfig utility will now launch.

Click on the **Boot** tab. Among the checkboxes at the bottom under **Boot Options**, click the checkbox next to **Safe boot** and select **Minimal** (if you really need network access while you are in safe mode you can select **Network** instead). Click OK.

Reboot the guest, and it will boot into safe mode. Once you have completed the installation, you need to reopen msconfig as above and uncheck **Safe boot**, to boot next into normal mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the problem is the VM will not boot at all or it only boots to require activation which in turn will not work until you can get into the OS.

In this case you can get F8 to be passed to the guest OS by turning on the "on screen keyboard". In Windows this is under control panel --> "ease of access center".

Comment: I think you mean using Control Panel in a host Windows system to implement the onscreen keyboard, for purposes of entering F8 into a guest Windows system. OP was asking about Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> key while you press <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> etc. (otherwise they are actually "multimedia" keys like Play/Pause)

Comment: That's primarily the case on a laptop as distinct from desktop keyboard, no?